# How to access the image data of the obstacle avoidance sensor of DJI Phantom 4 using Mobile SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I would like to access visual data from the stereo vision cameras used by Phantom 4 for obstacle avoidance. I like to use it to find if the obstacle is a human and localize the human position w.r.t the DJI camera. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible on the Phantom 4 or the MobileSDK. You can achieve this with the M210 and the OnboardSDK though.